# draw path using polylines from a xml file

Tags: xml, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

I want to draw a path on google maps using coordinates gotten from a xml file. I have the next code, but it doesnt work:

Does anyone know how to do it?

Best regards.

```
downloadUrl("myfile.asp", function(data) {
    var xml = xmlParse(data);
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    var points = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
    var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);

      }//finish loop

    var lineCoordinates = [ new google.maps.LatLng(point)];

     var path = new google.maps.Polyline({
path: lineCoordinates,
strokeColor: "#FF0000",
strokeOpacity: 1.0,
strokeWeight: 2
 });
  path.setMap(map);

    }); //end download url
```

And the xml file constains this data:

```
<markers>
<marker imei="1887" lat="37.184872837428" lng="-3.86559306991389"/>
<marker imei="1887" lat="37.1853220115895" lng="-3.86580098489519"/>
<marker imei="1887" lat="37.1852771929778" lng="-3.86576667518516"/>
<marker imei="1887" lat="37.185537832391" lng="-3.86587104505817"/>
<marker imei="1887" lat="37.1852233612396" lng="-3.86573226263189"/>
<marker imei="1887" lat="37.1851605163743" lng="-3.86569774724824"/>
<marker imei="1887" lat="37.185510710715" lng="-3.86588200146997"/>
<marker imei="1887" lat="37.1855652010503" lng="-3.86582629326349"/>
<marker imei="1887" lat="37.1855560232803" lng="-3.86584872061447"/>
</markers>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing the path array

```
downloadUrl("myfile.asp", function(data) {
    var xml = xmlParse(data);
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    var path = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
      var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
      path.push(point);
    }//finish loop

    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: path,
      strokeColor: "#FF0000",
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2
    });
    polyline.setMap(map);

}); //end download url
```

[Working example that parses XML to polylines in v3](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GenericMapBrowser.asp?filename=I5Polyline.xml)

Comment: do you know how can i remove the path? I m trying with this function:    function removePath() {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
    path[i].setMap(null);
  }
}

Comment: That is another question (and has been asked before recently).  You need to setMap(null) on the polyline, not the points in the path.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry. But I have tried also with this line of code into a function and does not work function removePath() {
  polyline.setMap(null)
}