# Create polyline in Google Maps 3 using an XML file

Tags: xml, google-maps-api-3

I am upgrading to v3 of Google maps and am having some trouble getting my polyline to load. I've based my code off the answer given in this link: [draw path using polylines from a xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459202/draw-path-using-polylines-from-a-xml-file) with a couple of variations to match my XML file.

```
downloadUrl("byway.xml", function(doc) {
    var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);
        var trks = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("trk");
        var bywaypath = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < trks.length; i++) {
            var trkPoints = trks[i].getElementsByTagName("trkpt");
            for (var j = 0; j<trkPoints.length; j++) {
    var lat = parseFloat(trkPoints[j].getAttribute("lat"));
  var lng = parseFloat(trkPoints[j].getAttribute("lng"));
  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
  bywaypath.push(point);
            }
        }


  var myPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path: bywaypath,
  strokeColor: "#008eb0",
  strokeOpacity: 1.0,
  strokeWeight: 3
});
```

myPath.setMap(map);
                                        });

Here is what my XML file looks like:

```
<gpx version="1.1" creator="RouteBuddy" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd">

<wpt lat="30.23041000" lon="-88.02368200">
<ele>935.481445</ele>
<trk>
    <name>ACC</name>
    <trkseg>

<trkpt lat="    30.23047759 " lon=" -88.02365995    "></trkpt>
<trkpt lat="    30.23040677 " lon=" -88.02368044    "></trkpt>
<trkpt lat="    30.23041    " lon=" -88.023682  "></trkpt>
<trkpt lat="    30.230062   " lon=" -88.023445  "></trkpt>
<trkpt lat="    30.229971   " lon=" -88.023339  "></trkpt>
<trkpt lat="    30.229628   " lon=" -88.022956  "></trkpt>
<trkpt lat="    30.229628   " lon=" -88.022956  "></trkpt>
<trkpt lat="    30.22975762 " lon=" -88.02288814    "></trkpt>
<trkpt lat="    30.22973402 " lon=" -88.02284032    "></trkpt>
<trkpt lat="    30.22973402 " lon=" -88.02284032    "></trkpt>
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. is your XML valid?
2. this doesn't look consistent (your code is looking for the attribute "lng", the XML contains the attribute "lon":

   ```
   var lng = parseFloat(trkPoints[j].getAttribute("lng"));


   <trkpt lat="    30.23047759 " lon=" -88.02365995    "></trkpt>
   ```

Comment: Well I am embarrassed that you had to help me figure that out, but so thankful you saw that simple mistake. I changed it to lon and all is working now. Thank you!!!

Comment: And by the way, thank you for all your examples online for Google maps. They have helped me in several projects!